# Исключить все строки где после символа есть набор букв

Tags: delphi

**Дан текст:**

```
123456789:aaaa-!-www
123456789:aaaa-Z-www
1234-!-56789:aaaawww
12345-Z-6789:aaaawww
```

**Задание:** В **edit** - пишем символы **"!" и "Z"** и программа исключает все строки, **где после знака ":"** - имеются символы **"!" и "Z".**

**На выходе должно получится:**

```
1234-!-56789:aaaawww
12345-Z-6789:aaaawww
```

**Сделала вот так:** Работает, но у меня почему то - **учитывается вся строка**. А нужно что бы **поиск происходил после - символа ":"** . Как это исправить ?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  D = [' ', #9, #10, #13];
var
fall, f1: TextFile;
Da : set of Char;
i, Len, LenW, CntA : Integer;
S,L, R: String;
g:Tstringlist;

begin
//Открываем диалог выбора файла
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
g:=Tstringlist.Create;
//Составляем множетсво букв. В множество добавляем строчный и заглавный
  //варианты букв.
  S := Edit1.Text; // В Edit записываем список символов
  Da := [];
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    if not (S[i] in D) then
      Da := Da + [ AnsiUpperCase(S[i])[1], AnsiLowerCase(S[i])[1] ];
  if Da = [] then begin
    ShowMessage('Буквы не заданы. Действие отменено.');
    Exit;
  end;

  AssignFile(fall, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  reset(fall);
  end;
//работаем по строкам в файле
 while not Eof(fall) do
  begin
 //читаем строку
  ReadLn(fall, S);
  Len := Length(S);
  LenW := 0;
  CntA := 0;
  for i := 1 to Len do begin
    //Пропускаем разделители.
    if S[i] in D then Continue;
    //Подсчёт заданных букв в слове.
    if S[i] in Da then Inc(CntA);
    //Уточняем длину слова.
    Inc(LenW);
    //Отслеживаем конец слова.
    if (i = Len) or (S[i + 1] in D) then begin
      //Если заданных букв нет в слове - распечатываем его.
      if CntA = 0 then
      // Записываем рзультат
      g.Add( Copy(S, i - LenW + 1, LenW) );
      //Сброс счётчика заданных букв.
      CntA := 0;
      //Сброс длины слова.
      LenW := 0;

   end;
  end;
  end;

  g.SaveToFile('Результат.txt');
  g.Free;
CloseFile(fall);
end;
```

Comment: Судя по примеру - условие должно быть "символы "!" **или** "Z"."?  А где в коде участвует двоеточие?

Comment: @MBo, Именно тут (на этом моменте я застряла) я и не могу додуматься - где именно прописать проверку с двоеточием, что бы поиск осуществлялся после двоеточия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bSemicolon := False;
for i := 1 to Length(S) do
   case S[i] of
     ':' : bSemicolon := True;
     '!','Z': if bSemiColon then
            что-то делать, можно остановить цикл Break;
      else ... //что-то делать для других символов
   end;
```

Кроме того, можно использовать Pos с заданием стартовой позиции

```
BadChars := '!Z';

sPos := Pos(":", s);
if sPos > 0 then 
   for k = 1 to Length(BadChars) do
      if (Pos(BadChars[k], s, sPos + 1) > 0) then
         s плохая
```

Comment: Использовать Pos с заданием стартовой позиции, это я так поняла - с какого по счету символа ":" начинать поиск или ?

Comment: С Pos(':') + 1. Вам такие примеры показывали много раз.

Comment: Не получилось, ладно, может я что то не то делаю. Буду думать.

Comment: Не получилось с каким подходом?

Comment: С подходом Pos(':') + 1, не понимаю что не так делаю, но все равно поиск осуществляется по всей строке. а должно быть после символа ":".

Comment: код с Pos добавил

Comment: Код то работает, но я имела в виду что в моем коде можно указывать список символов в Edit по которым отсеивать строки а Pos изначально для этого не предназначен. Ну и на этом спасибо - буду изучать дальше код, возможно что то придумаю.

Comment: Можно перебрать в цикле pos со всеми символами.

Comment: В цикле как правильно будет ? Можете добавить в ответ..

Comment: Правильно, но нерационально. Добавил.

Comment: Спасибо, согласна, расход ресурсов идет и по скорости. Вот бы мой код исправить. Там очень быстрая обработка, просто не могу полностью все сообразить. Если получится сделать то обязательно напишу ответ.